# Pop-up window with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, popup

This is what I want to achieve: I want a pop-up window to appear as soon as I click on any web element on a web page. The pop-up window should be able to list out each property associated to the element (name, id, class name, css, xpath) as a radio button. I have a format to define in what order the properties need to be displayed. So in case any property for an element is not defined, I want it to be left blank.

I have Java code that has Javascript embedded in it to do the job. Here is a part of the code:

```
public String createHTMLForInputTag()
{
   String temp = "";
   temp += "{ ";
   temp += "   var x = document.getElementsByTagName('input');";
   temp += "   var i = 0;";
   temp += "   for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)";
   temp += "   {";
   temp += "      x[i].title = x[i].name;";
   temp += "      x[i].onclick = function()";
   temp += "      {";
   temp += "          var previousStyle = this.style.getAttribute('cssText');";
   temp += "          this.style.setAttribute('cssText', 'color: yellow; border: 2px solid yellow');";
   temp += "          var temp5;";
   temp += "          var temp1 = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');";
   temp += "          temp1 = 'Name : ' + this.name;";
   temp += "          var temp2 = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');";
   temp += "          temp2 = 'Type : ' + this.type;";
           //code continues...
}
```

What I'm able to do for now: Retrieve the properties of the element and paste the same to clipboard. But the properties get pasted in a single line like the below quoted example:
Name : qType : textID : Class name : lst

What I need help for:
1. Way to paste each property on a new line
2. Way to push the properties dynamically to the pop-up

Any help appreciated! Thanks!